# numpy array elementwise multiply a panda timeseries

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have these two data structures:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
ts = pd.TimeSeries([1,2,3])
```

What I want to get at the end is:

```
1  2  3
2  4  6
3  6  9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the outer product:

```
In [490]: np.outer(a, ts)
Out[490]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Or align one of them vertically first:

```
In [491]: a * ts[:, None]
Out[491]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Note that the strange index just makes it a column vector:

```
In [493]: ts[:, None]
Out[493]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

by adding an extra length-1 dimension to the shape:

```
In [494]: ts[:, None].shape
Out[494]: (3, 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> np.outer(a, ts)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```